# Can you execute concordion.net tests using TestDriven.Net or directly from Visual Studio?

Tags: testing, nunit, testdriven.net, concordion

Is it possible to run tests written in Concordion.Net using some form of Visual Studio addin?  I am looking to start using Concordion.Net.  However, I was used to running tests from Visual Studio directly through the Resharper plugin.  Since Concordion.Net is a different concept, and uses HTML files to 'specify' the tests, one cannot use the Resharper plugin.

You can run them using the nUnit GUI, but it is a bit of a pain to use it and slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TestDriven.NET (http://testdriven.net/) to execute Concordion.NET tests within Visual Studio. To run a test please use the "Run Test(s)" command of TestDriven.NET on your Concordion.NET fixture class (http://testdriven.net/quickstart.aspx).

Please, make sure that you have specified the [assembly: RequiredAddin("ConcordionNUnitAddin")] attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs of your specification project as described in the how to "Run Concordion.NET Tests with NUnit" (http://concordion.org/dotnet/RunningTests.html).

When you run Concordion.NET tests with TestDriven.NET in Visual Studio, you should see an output similar to:
“------ Test started: Assembly: Concordion.Spec.dll ------
Processed specifications : C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\Concordion\Spec\Concordion\Command\AssertEquals\NonString\Boolean.html
1 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, took 0,67 seconds (NUnit 2.6.2).”

To be able to run Concordion.NET tests with TestDriven.NET you have to install the Concordion.NUnit.dll into the installation directory of TestDriven.NET (C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET\NUnit\2.6\addins\Concordion.NUnit.dll).

Comment: The TestDriven.Net solution you gave worked! Thanks a lot this will save me heaps of time - the nUnit GUI is very frustrating to work with if you have thousands of test. Thanks!

Comment: in the meantime I discovered that the "hack" with adding an additional [TestFixture] annotation is not necessary - you just need to add the [assembly: RequiredAddin("ConcordionNUnitAddin")] attribute to your AssemblyInfo.cs of your specification project in Visual Studio. Then TestDriven.NET recognizes that Concordion.NET tests should be run with NUnit out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Concordion.NET tests can be run with the help of NUnit (http://concordion.org/dotnet/RunningTests.html) based on the Concordion NUnit addin. When NUnit discovers a class containing Concordion.NET fixture code annotated with [ConcordionTest], the Concordion.NUnit addin loads the related HTML specification document and creates a test instance that is executed with the help of NUnit.

Unfortunatelly, ReSharper uses a different mechanism to find tests than NUnit(http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/4.09+Test+Framework+Support+%28R8%29). Thus, it would be necessary to write a ReSharper plugin to recognize classes annotated with [ConcordionTest] and use the ReSharper NUnit support to execute them. NUnit 3.0 will probably comply with interfaces consumed by ReSharper.

On the other Hand, the current version of the NUnit Adapter for Visual Studio (http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.2) is not able to load NUnit addins appropriately. An update of NUnit is necessary, which is planned for NUnit 3.0 (https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/issues/9).

To run Concordion.NET tests in Visual Studio you can use TestDriven.NET as described above.